# How do I make free movement of an svg element with the Shift+Left button Mouse pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I need a circle that is created when you click on a free area to be able to move freely throughout the page when the Shift+Left button Mouse is pressed.

Simply put I need to be able to move this circle around the entire page area while holding down Shift+Left button Mouse.

Before trying to respond run the code and click on an empty area.

```js
let svg = document.querySelector("svg")
let bg = document.querySelector("svg rect")

function click(e) {
  svg.innerHTML += `
    <g transform="translate(${e.clientX},${e.clientY})">
      <circle onclick="split(this)" r="50"></circle>
    </g>
  `;
}

function split(el){
  el.parentNode.innerHTML = [...Array(4)].map((_,i) => `
    <path d="M-50,0A50,50,0,0,0,0,50L0,0z" 
          onclick=merge(this) 
          transform="rotate(${-45+i*90})"></path>
  `);
}

function merge(el){
  el.parentNode.innerHTML =  `<circle onclick="split(this)" r="50"></circle>`;
}

function resize() {
  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", [0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight]);
}

resize();
addEventListener("resize", resize);
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden
}
path, circle {
    transition: 100ms;
    fill: #0001;
    stroke: black;
  }
  
  path:hover, circle:hover {
    fill: rgba(15, 250, 113, 0.133);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <title>Redactor marshrutov</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu1.css">
</head>
<body>
   
    <svg>
        <rect fill="white" width="1440" height="900" onclick="click(event)"></rect>
      </svg>
           
    <script type="text/javascript" src="menu1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to get acquainted with `html drag and drop element` mechanism. Which can be a real drag (no pun intended!) Your code shows nothing of the sort and I think it would be too much for now to answer. Here is a good start [Draggable SVG elements](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/dragging/) and see if that works for you.

Comment: Well thanks for the links I will read